# MATLAB: Plotting/Saving X-Y views of mesh function in subplots

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, mesh, subplot

As the title says, I'm trying to save the 2-variable slices of a mesh function (as a .jpg, for example) as a subplot. I want to do this using a .m file because I have many plots to generate. I have figured out how to plot the views on their own figures, but I cannot get them to plot properly as subplots within a figure. To illustrate what I mean:

Here are the outputs on individual plots:
3D mesh: [3D MATLAB mesh plot](http://i39.tinypic.com/xnra76.jpg)
XY view: [XY MATLAB mesh view](http://i39.tinypic.com/25ktrhy.jpg)
YZ view: [YZ MATLAB mesh view](http://i39.tinypic.com/hvuuio.jpg)
XZ view: [XZ MATLAB mesh view](http://i41.tinypic.com/14ttv9c.jpg)

And here is my plotting code (not working):

```
%Ambiguity Surface
fid = figure(fnum);
    axes1 = axes('Parent',fid);
    view(axes1,[-62.5 28]);
    grid(axes1,'on');
    hold(axes1,'all');
    msh = mesh(taux,fdy,z,'Parent',axes1);
    xlabel ('Delay - seconds');
    ylabel ('Doppler - Hz');
    zlabel ('Ambiguity function (Normalized Magnitude-Squared)');
    fname = strcat(name,' (Ambiguity Function z(\tau;F_d))');
    title(fname);
    cb = colorbar('peer',axes1);
    set(get(cb,'ylabel'),'String','Magnitude-Squared (dB)');
    hold off;
    printFig(fid,fnum,sname)
    fnum = fnum + 1;

%Ambiguity Slices
fid = figure(fnum);
    hold all;
    subplot(2,1,1);
        axes1 = axes();
        grid(axes1,'on');
        view(axes1,[90 0]);
        msh = mesh(taux,fdy,z);
        xlabel ('Delay - seconds','Visible','off');
        ylabel ('Doppler - Hz');
        zlabel ('Ambiguity function (Normalized Magnitude-Squared)','Visible','off');
        fname = strcat(name,' (Ambiguity Function Slice z(\tau;F_d) @ \tau = 128)');
        title(fname)
    subplot(2,1,2);
        axes2 = axes();
        grid(axes2,'on');
        view(axes2,[0 0]);
        msh = mesh(taux,fdy,z);
        xlabel ('Delay - seconds','Visible','off');
        ylabel ('Doppler - Hz','Visible','off');
        zlabel ('Ambiguity function (Normalized Magnitude-Squared)','Visible','off');
        cb = colorbar('peer',axes2);
        set(get(cb,'ylabel'),'String','Magnitude-Squared');
        fname = strcat(name,' (Ambiguity Function Slice z(\tau;F_d) @ F_d = 0)');
        title(fname)
    hold off;
    printFig(fid,fnum,slname)
    fnum = fnum+1;
```

printFig() just sets up directory info and does `print` command.

My code sets up the two subplots and then overlays a full 3-d view of the mesh plot, which is not what I want. I'd like to see two of the views (XZ and YZ) on a single figure.

Thanks for the help!

-Dylan

EDIT:
Per @Andrew_L's suggestion, I modified this in my code:

```
sp1 = subplot(2,1,1);
       axes(sp1);
       axes1 = axes();
       grid(axes1,'on');
       view(axes1,[90 0]);
       msh = mesh(taux,fdy,z,'Parent',axes1);
```

This is repeated for the other subplot. The result is still the same, however. It appears to set up the two blank subplots properly and then display the full pseudo-3D plot over it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a stripped example very similar to what you are trying to achieve:

```
%# create axes, and set the view of each
hAx(1) = subplot(221); h = mesh(peaks);   view(3)
hAx(2) = subplot(222); copyobj(h,hAx(2)); view(0,90), title('X-Y')
hAx(3) = subplot(223); copyobj(h,hAx(3)); view(0,0) , title('X-Z')
hAx(4) = subplot(224); copyobj(h,hAx(4)); view(90,0), title('Y-Z')

%# set properties of axes
for i=1:4
    grid(hAx(i), 'on')
    axis(hAx(i), 'tight')
    xlabel(hAx(i), 'Delay (sec)');
    ylabel(hAx(i), 'Doppler (Hz)');
    zlabel(hAx(i), 'Ambiguity function');
end
title(hAx(1), 'Short Tone Ping z(\tau;F_d)')
hc = colorbar('Peer',hAx(1));
set(get(hc,'YLabel'), 'String','Magnitude-Squared (dB)')
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Take a look at this one, please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963459/matlab-how-to-bend-line-in-image/8032684#8032684 I think you could help

Comment: I went with Andrew_L's solution, although yours appears to work as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `axes1 = axes();` right below `subplot(2,1,1);`, you are setting `axes1` to the default full-window axis when you call `axes()` without any arguments, which is causing the overlap. Instead, try using the handle returned by `subplot` to generate the axes handle. Try the following code for the second section:

```
%Ambiguity Slices
fid = figure(fnum);
    H1 = subplot(2,1,1);
        pos1 = get(H1, 'Position');
        set(H1,'Position',[pos1(1) pos1(2) 0.8*pos1(3) pos1(4)]); %leave space for colorbar;
        grid on;
        msh = mesh(taux,fdy,z);
        view([90 0]);
        mapping = caxis;
        xlabel ('Delay - seconds','Visible','off');
        ylabel ('Doppler - Hz');
        zlabel ('Ambiguity function (Normalized Magnitude-Squared)','Visible','off');
        fname = strcat(name,' (Ambiguity Function Slice z(\tau;F_d) @ \tau = 128)');
        title(fname)
    H2 = subplot(2,1,2);
        pos2 = get(H2, 'Position');
        set(H2,'Position',[pos2(1) pos2(2) 0.8*pos2(3) pos2(4)]); %leave space for colorbar;
        grid on;
        msh = mesh(taux,fdy,z);
        caxis(mapping);
        view([0 0]);
        xlabel ('Delay - seconds','Visible','off');
        ylabel ('Doppler - Hz','Visible','off');
        zlabel ('Ambiguity function (Normalized Magnitude-Squared)','Visible','off');
    axes('Position', [0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9], 'Visible', 'off'); %setup axes for colorbar;
    caxis(mapping);
    cb = colorbar();
    ylabel(cb, 'Magnitude-Squared');
    fname = strcat(name,' (Ambiguity Function Slice z(\tau;F_d) @ F_d = 0)');
    title(fname)
    printFig(fid,fnum,slname)
    fnum = fnum+1;
```

This (should) at least get everything displayed how you want - I believe that the colorbar scale will not correspond to anything in particular (most likely the number of discrete colors in the bar), so extra code is needed to make sure both plots use the same colormap, and that you change the colormap for the colorbar.

Comment: I have tried that, when I do this is the error I get:

    ??? Error using ==> axes
    Too many output arguments.
    
    Error in ==> plotSurfaces at 51
               axes1 = axes(sp1);

Comment: I just tried setting axes to the subplot: 'axes(sp1)' and then typing 'axes1 = axes()' to get the values. Doing this sets up the axes properly on the plot (for both subplots), but then it is overlaid with the pseudo-3d plot instead of the desired view.

Comment: I modified the answer above to get a workable solution. I changed the size of the subplots to make room for a global colorbar using the `'Position'` property, then set up a color bar using the larger axes created by the `axes()` command. The code could be greatly simplified if you use two separate colorbars, one for each subplot. (The above code draws one large colorbar, but more work is needed to get the scale accurate).

Comment: This is close!! Here is my result: [link](http://i44.tinypic.com/2z524wg.jpg) The plot looks great, but the 'view()' command didn't change the view. The result was the exact same pseudo-3D view for both. I tried changing the input vector to view() and it always produced the same. The views that are supposed to be produced are XZ and YZ, respectively.

Comment: Seems like the `view()` command is working, but the `mesh()` command is resetting the viewpoint to the default. Placing the view command to  after mesh() should fix it. I'll correct the above code. Also, I've added in a couple lines with the `caxis` function, which should make sure that the second subplot has the same color mapping, and that the colorbar values correspond to the plots. (eg. in your linked image, dark red does not equal 65)