# Matlab: How to bend line in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, line

I have a image(png format) in hand. The lines that bound the ellipses (represent the nucleus) are over straight which are impractical. How could i extract the lines from the image and make them bent, and with the precondition that they still enclose the nucleus.

The following is the  image:
[image]

After bending

[image]

**EDIT**: How can i translate the **Dilation And Filter** part in answer2 into **Matlab** language? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you talking about the black lines?

Comment: And what do you mean by "bent", in this case. Can you perhaps choose one line in the image and draw how it should look after "bending" it?

Comment: @Ivy Depends on how many of these you need, but honestly the best phantom for this type of thing would seem to be a thresholded/simplified image derived from a real image like your example.

Comment: @John I think it can be done simulating some kind of random growing from the core ellipses, but I still can not get it wrking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is a way involving several randomization steps needed to get a "natural" non symmetrical appearance.

I am posting the actual code in Mathematica, just in case someone cares translating it to Matlab.

```
(* A preparatory step: get your image and clean it*)
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/YENhB.png";
i1 = Image@Replace[ImageData[i], {0., 0., 0.} -> {1, 1, 1}, {2}];
i2 = ImageSubtract[i1, i];
i3 = Inpaint[i, i2]
```

[image]

```
(*Now reduce to a skeleton to get a somewhat random starting point.  
The actual algorithm for this dilation does not matter, as far as we 
get a random area slightly larger than the original elipses *)
id = Dilation[SkeletonTransform[
             Dilation[SkeletonTransform@ColorNegate@Binarize@i3, 3]], 1]
```

[image]

```
(*Now the real random dilation loop*)
(*Init vars*)
p = Array[1 &, 70]; j = 1;
(*Store in w an image with a different color for each cluster, so we 
can find edges between them*)
w = (w1 = 
      WatershedComponents[
       GradientFilter[Binarize[id, .1], 1]]) /. {4 -> 0} // Colorize;
(*and loop ...*)
For[i = 1, i < 70, i++,
 (*Select edges in w and dilate them with a random 3x3 kernel*)
 ed = Dilation[EdgeDetect[w, 1], RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]];
 (*The following is the core*)
 p[[j++]] = w =
   ImageFilter[  (* We apply a filter to the edges*)
    (Switch[
          Length[#1],  (*Count the colors in a 3x3 neighborhood of each pixel*)
          0, {{{0, 0, 0}, 0}},          (*If no colors, return bkg*)
          1, #1,                        (*If one color, return it*)
          _, {{{0, 0, 0}, 0}}])[[1, 1]] (*If more than one color, return bkg*)&@
      Cases[Tally[Flatten[#1, 1]], 
       Except[{{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, _}]] & (*But Don't count bkg pixels*),
    w, 1,
    Masking -> ed,       (*apply only to edges*)
    Interleaving -> True (*apply to all color chanels at once*)]
 ]
```

The result is:

[image]

**Edit**

For the Mathematica oriented reader, a functional code for the last loop could be easier (and shorter):

```
NestList[
 ImageFilter[  
   If[Length[#1] ==  1, #1[[1, 1]], {0, 0, 0}] &@
     Cases[Tally[Flatten[#1, 1]], Except[{0.` {1, 1, 1}, _}]] & , #, 1,
   Masking      -> Dilation[EdgeDetect[#, 1], RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]],  
   Interleaving -> True ] &,
 WatershedComponents@GradientFilter[Binarize[id,.1],1]/.{4-> 0}//Colorize, 
5]
```

Comment: The algorithm you used above, if my understanding is correct, you assign different colors to the watershed regions and once the dilation meet each other,it will return the edge in background color which is in black. It works great in Mathematica. Now i'm trying to apply this method in matlab, hope i can meke it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivy Yes. Beware of the randomization part. If you don't, you will end up with a beautiful squared tartan patchwork. Good luck!

Comment: @Ivy The user Amro is a master in the art of translating Mathematica to Matlab ... just in case

Comment: thanks for the vote of confidence but that's a difficult one to translate (I am still learning Mathematica myself)... Anyways I will take a look as soon as I can and report back. very nice solution btw +1

Comment: @Amro You largely deserve my praise! Anyway, if you are learning Mma, remember to check out the Mma tag questions and answers in SO. There a lot of knowledgeable users to learn from.

Comment: I posted a solution, wasn't successful in completely replicating your solution (among other things, there is no equivalent for the `Masking` option of the `ImageFilter` function in MATLAB), but at least should give OP some ideas :)

Comment: @belisarius: congrats, although I would have preferred it to stay inside SO. It's getting hard to keep track of all SE sites i'm interested in..

Comment: @Amro Completely agree, but the Mma community preferred it this way.

Answer (score 7):

What you have as input is the Voronoi diagram. You can recalculate it using another distance function instead of the Euclidean one.

Here is an example in Mathematica using the Manhattan Distance (`i3` is your input image without the lines):

```
ColorCombine[{Image[
   WatershedComponents[
    DistanceTransform[Binarize@i3, 
      DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance] ]], i3, i3}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

I am working with another algorithm (preliminary result). What do you think?

[image]

Comment: The OP wants more life-like cells. i.e. *less* like the Voronoi diagram. Look in the example photo and you'll see some cells have more pressure or whatever and bulge out and squish the others.

Comment: @John I understand that. I am trying to keep things simple. I'll try another shot when work allows.

Comment: Nice! I will follow this post. It's a neat problem.

Comment: @John What do think of my new drawing? I'm still working out some details!

Comment: That's really awesome. I love it!

Comment: @John I finished the algorithm, but no time to post it right now. The whole thing is rather convoluted because all simple solutions end up in symmetrical configurations. Several randomization steps are needed to get a (more or less) "natural" appearance. I will post my Frankenstein tomorrow.

Comment: @belisarius Could you pls explain more on the algorithm that you working with?

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I came up with, it is not a direct translation of [@belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963459/matlab-how-to-bend-line-in-image/8032684#8032684) code, but should be close enough..

```
%# read image (indexed image)
[I,map] = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/YENhB.png');

%# extract the blobs (binary image)
BW = (I==1);

%# skeletonization + dilation
BW = bwmorph(BW, 'skel', Inf);
BW = imdilate(BW, strel('square',2*1+1));

%# connected components
L = bwlabel(BW);
imshow(label2rgb(L))

%# filter 15x15 neighborhood
for i=1:13
    L = nlfilter(L, [15 15], @myFilterFunc);
    imshow( label2rgb(L) )
end

%# result
L(I==1) = 0;                %# put blobs back
L(edge(L,'canny')) = 0;     %# edges
imshow( label2rgb(L,@jet,[0 0 0]) )
```

#### myFilterFunc.m

```
function p = myFilterFunc(x)
    if range(x(:)) == 0
        p = x(1);                %# if one color, return it
    else
        p = mode(x(x~=0));       %# else, return the most frequent color
    end
end
```

The result:

[image: screenshot]

and here is an animation of the process:

[image: animation]

Comment: +1 Nice. The masking was used in my answer to provide an extra randomization step. Anyway, I think this is good enough for a start. Congrats!

Comment: @Amro:Neighboring section cost time...whatever, that's really cool!