# Matlab: Material on image color processing

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I need to do color processing of an image under Matlab, but i'm short of knowledge about it. Any shared links,examples,material would be appreciated. Thanks. (This is related to link [How to bend line in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963459/matlab-how-to-bend-line-in-image))

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to draw artificial graphics based on some synthetic image?

Comment: You should look at the documentation for the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/).

Comment: can you please be more specific? i have no clue what you are trying to do.