# How to determine if axes are 2D or 3D in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, properties, plot, axes

As stated, what is the easiest way to determine programmatically if a Matlab axes object is a 2D or 3D plot?

Comment: All axes are 3d, but Nzbuu's answer will indicate that you're viewing it as 2d.

Comment: Yes, I knew this, but there are differences in what happens when you use zoom on an axis viewed in 3D rather than 2D which is why I need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine the output of `[az,el] = view`. If it's 2D, then `el == 90`.

Comment: although technically the answer to my question is `[az,el] = view(hax)` where `hax` is a handle to the axes of interest. Thanks!

Comment: as you can see from this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960059/matlab-plotting-saving-x-y-views-of-mesh-function-in-subplots/8059484#8059484), there are more 2D cases (as well as their rotated versions)

Comment: The answer by Jeff Fessler (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723959/6651650) is a more robust solution.

Comment: You can rotate a 3D plot to have `el=90`, it’s still a 3D plot.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for the `axis` function:

> `V = axis` returns a row vector containing the scaling for the current plot.  If the current view is 2-D, `V` has four components; if it is 3-D, `V` has six components.

Thus, you can get the dimension of the axes by calling

```
plot_dim = numel(axis)/2;
```

It will return `2` for 2D and `3` for 3D.

If you have a reference `ax` to an `axes` object, you can modify the above code by passing `ax` to `axis`:

```
plot_dim = numel(ax)/2;
```