# MATLAB Patch Creates Skewed Map of Vermont

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, patch

I've been exploring 2D Plot defaults, Patch and other documentation, as well as Matlab forums for a solution to this problem and have none after 3 months of looking.

I am using line segment data to draw U.S. Census districts of Vermont, thereby creating a map of the state. The ~185 patches that constitute Vermont create a graph that is slightly tilted to the left, as if the 2D drawing is being projected onto a 3D plane. I have the same issue with Delaware data.

Why does Patch(x,y) insist on patching in a tilted manner, even when I go through the Figure window and all signs say it is displaying in 2D?

Edit 1: Using `[az,el] = view` I get `el == 90`, meaning my plot is definitely 2D, as described in [How to determine if axes are 2D or 3D in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064969/how-to-determine-if-axes-are-2d-or-3d-in-matlab)