# Matlab: 2D projection of a 3D function

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, projection

I have a function `f(x,y)= Exp(-x^2-y^-2)(x^2+y^2)`. I would like to look at the projection of this function onto the x-axis in MATLAB.

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: related question: [MATLAB: Plotting/Saving X-Y views of mesh function in subplots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960059/matlab-plotting-saving-x-y-views-of-mesh-function-in-subplots)

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
xs = [];
ys = [];
zs = [];
for x = -10:0.1:10
    for y = -10:0.1:10
        xs = [xs x];
        ys = [ys y];
        z = f(x,y);
        zs = [zs z];
    end
end
figure; plot3(xs,ys,zs);  %plots the full function over both dimensions
figure; plot(xs,zs,'rx'); %plots the projection onto the x axis
figure; plot(ys,zs,'rx'); %plots the projection onto the y axis
```

that does it over the range -10 to 10 along both x and y but you can change that accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

@Amro has a great solution, but you might also take a look at Scott Hirsch's awesome [shadowplot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6400-SHADOWPLOT) from the MATLAB Central File Exchange. Check it out:

```
>> f = @(x,y) exp(-x.^2 -y.^(-2)).*(x.^2+y.^2);
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.5:10,-10:0.5:10);
>> surf(X,Y,f(X,Y))
>> xlim([-11,11])
>> ylim([-11,11])
>> shadowplot x
>> shadowplot y
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the [view](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/view.html) to see the 2D-projection on the x-axis:

```
f = @(x,y) exp(-x.^2 -y.^(-2)).*(x.^2+y.^2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.5:10,-10:0.5:10);
surf(X,Y,f(X,Y))
view(90,0), shading interp
xlabel X, ylabel Y, zlabel Z
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In figure by clicking rotate button if we select `Go To Y-Z View` doesn't this do the same thing?

Comment: @clarkson: Yes but I'm doing it programmatically. The X-Y view corresponds to `view(0,90)`, X-Z is `view(0,0)`, and Y-Z is `view(90,0)`